# What are basic steps for installing a third party theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, command-line

**[ Asking for the proper sequence and  the basic steps ]**

Hello, I am beginner to Magento 2, and its folder structure.

I am trying to install a theme in M2, and has finally installed. But to achieved I had tried some more efforts(google and stack overflow).

So, My questions is as below:

1. Why we need to give permissions to our magento2 folder every time.
2. What are the basic steps for installing theme in magento2.
3. What are the importance/requirement of  commands for (deploy/index/compile).
4. How many ways of installing theme in magento2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to install a theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not have to do that, please explain.
2. [How to install a theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)
3. [Which directories to clear and when[(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html)
4. There is probably a completely manual way to do it. You can start [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/intro/developers_roadmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Steps to install theme in Magento 2:

First, download the theme of your choice.

Then Unzip the downloaded theme and upload the files to the root directory of your Magento 2 store.

Run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Lastly, go to **CONTENT → Configuration** to activate your theme.